# Get values from an item in gridview in MVC C# while is generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

Good Day:

I got this code to generate a gridview in MVC 4;

```
@{SATXmlReports.Models.User spp = new SATXmlReports.Models.User();
           var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData["GridUserData"] as IEnumerable<SATXmlReports.Models.User>, canPage: true, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: 10, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
          }
          <div id="gridContent" >
          @grid.GetHtml(
                        tableStyle: "table table-hover",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("Name", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Name.ToString())),
                        grid.Column("Rol","Rol"),
                                 grid.Column("User Sites", "UserSites", format: item => Html.DropDownList("Sites", SATXmlReports.Models.User.GetUserSites(item.Name.ToString()).Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.Description, Value = u.Number }))
                                 )))
```

But I get this error:

> Error 11  The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string,
>   System.Func, string, bool)' has some invalid
>   arguments c:\Users\fernando.martinez\Desktop\SATXmlReports\SATXmlReports\Views\Configuracion\UserSettings.cshtml  109 38  SATXmlReports

And:

> Error 12  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to
>   'System.Func' c:\Users\fernando.martinez\Desktop\SATXmlReports\SATXmlReports\Views\Configuracion\UserSettings.cshtml  109 83  SATXmlReports

I tried everything to get item properties, but I'm failing. This way is working, but is hardcoded:

```
grid.Column("User Sites", "UserSites", format: item => Html.DropDownList("Sites", SATXmlReports.Models.User.GetUserSites("John.Burdon").Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.Description, Value = u.Number }))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to beware of using extension methods with dynamics (item).

Try this:

```
grid.Column("User Sites", "UserSites", format: item => Html.DropDownList("Sites", SATXmlReports.Models.User.GetUserSites((string)item.Name).Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.Description, Value = u.Number }))
```